# How to solve the indefinite integral $\int \frac{x^{1 / 7}+x^{1 / 2}}{x^{8 / 7}+x^{1 / 14}} \ \mathrm{d} x$?

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals

I need to calculate a complicated indefinite integral below:
$$\int \frac{x^{1 / 7}+x^{1 / 2}}{x^{8 / 7}+x^{1 / 14}} \ \mathrm{d} x$$
Can you help me to find out how it solved?I think my answer by using the exchange methods three times:
$$
70\ln \left|4x^{5/7}-4x^{5/14}+4\right|-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\arctan \left(\frac{2x^{5/14}-1}{\sqrt{3}}\right) + x^{5/14} + C
$$
is wrong.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please edit your query to show the details of what you are referring to as the exchange method.  This way, you will have shown your work, and mathSE reviewers can examine this work step by step, looking for any mistake that you might have made.

Answer (score 5):

Hint:

As $[2,7,14]=14,$

Let $x^{1/14}=y, x=y^{14}, dx=14y^{13}dy$

$$\int\dfrac{y^2+y^7}{y^{16}+y}\cdot14y^{13}dy$$

$$=14\int\dfrac{y^{15}(1+y^5)}{y(1+y^{15})}dy$$

$$=14\int\dfrac{y^{10}}{1-y^5+y^{10}}\cdot y^4dy$$

Set $y^5=z$

The rest is left as an exercise!

Answer (score 2):

You should apply the substitution: $x = t^{14}$

This will get you a rational function of $t$.

And then... as we know all rational functions can be integrated,
there is a well-known procedure for that.